# Change the screen capture key combination?

Tags: 8.0, lumia, settings, 8.1, lumia-520

In 8.0 it was win+power key combination, and I liked it this way.

Now it is volume+power key which is annoying(depends on person to person). How can I change it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it can be changed. The key combination is defined by Microsoft, and no customization can be made to it.